# Jquery clone input and remove the value in the cloned one

Tags: jquery, forms, input, clone

What I'm trying to archive is cloning my "box" and have a clone one without the values.
So the inputs should be empty. 
I've got this fiddle, with only the function and html.
Hope is clear and you guys can help me.

http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/117/

```
addAddress: function() {
    var cloneCount = 0;
    $copy = $("#scroll .first").first().clone().attr("id", "to-add-first_Clone" + cloneCount).addClass('cloned'); //add a new class cloned to the cloned outerDivs
    $(".clone", "#to-add-first_Clone" + cloneCount).attr("id", "clone_Clone" + cloneCount);
    cloneCount++;
    //check breakpoints
    var $last_bp = $('#scroll .wrap .breakpoint').last();
    var $first = $(".first", $last_bp).length;
    if ($first > 2) {
        //move this into a new breakpoint
        $('#scroll .wrap').append('<div class="breakpoint"/>');
        $last_bp = $('#scroll .wrap .breakpoint').last();
    }
    $last_bp.append($copy);
    this.drawNavigation();
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is the gist of what you are trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/132/

The newly cloned box will have empty input values. The delete address links show up intelligently and I added the logic to create new "unique" ids.

Comment: thanks but you removed my "breakpoint" div function. means I'm ow not able to wrap 3 divs in a div breakpoint.

Comment: I just need to clone, and have a cloned one without the input values.

Comment: Like I said, this is the gist of what you're trying to do. The extra logic you had in there for the breakpoints wasn't part of your question so I removed it for the sake of clarity and for a complete and functional system. If you need that, then you can certainly add it back in where it belongs.